# Vector field of point charges

Tags: plotting, vector

[image]

I need help in plotting vector field or stream field.
Can you please help me to plot electric field of these 13points standing on a circle which are all positive with same magnitude. The code for this shape by a friend here is:

```
or = Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0}]}];
g1 = ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}];
pp = Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}];
g2 = ListPlot[pp, PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[Large]}];
Show[g1, g2, or]
```

Comment: Could you post the _code_ not a picture? It's generally kind to the people donating their time to make it as easy as possible

Comment: or = Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0}]}];
g1 = ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}];
pp = Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/6}];
g2 = ListPlot[pp, PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[Large]}];
Show[g1, g2, or]

Comment: This is done by dear friend here